# JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'string' .NET

Tags: .net, mongodb

I'm running a select in mongoDb with the following code:

```
var projects = GenerateProject(customizations);
            var result = _mongoDbRepository
                    .SetDatabase("mydatabase")
                    .GetCollection(myCollection)
                    .Aggregate()
                    .Match(myFilter)
                    .Project<dynamic>(projects)
                    .ToList();
```

GenerateProject Class:

```
 private static string GenerateProject(List<MyClass> customizations)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("{ '_id':0");

        foreach (var item in customizations)
        {
            sb.Append(", '");
            sb.Append(item.Name);
            sb.Append("':1");
        }

        sb.Append(" }");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

but on return I get the error:

```
JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'string'
```

Can anyone tell me what could be going on?

Comment: Please don't build JSON by hand.

Comment: Also, JSON uses double quotes `"` for keys and string values not  single quotes `'`.

Comment: use BsonDocument to generate any json you need

Answer (score 0):

I try your code.

The problem is on your `match` stage. You should check what is inside your `myFilter`.

Works fine.

```cs
var customizations = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() { Name = "123", _id = "456" } };
var projects = GenerateProject(customizations);
var result = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("month")
      .Aggregate()
      .Match("{}")
      .Project<dynamic>(projects)
      .ToList();
```

Not work.

```cs
var customizations = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() { Name = "123", _id = "456" } };
var projects = GenerateProject(customizations);
var result = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("month")
      .Aggregate()
      .Match("")
      .Project<dynamic>(projects)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: that way passing "{}" worked, but how would I do it in my scenario where I get the filter inside an object?

Comment: would i have to serialize first? so var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjectFilter);

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if it's problem (but given the error, it's possible) but it looks like you're trying to manually create some JSON in the `GenerateProject` method manually.

Never, ever, ever attempt to generate JSON "by hand" like this, especially when there are dedicated tools to do this.

Add all of your entries to a `Dictionary<string, int>` and pass that to the serialiser to generate correct JSON.

```
private static string GenerateProject(List<MyClass> customizations)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dict.Add("_id", 0);

    foreach (var item in customizations)
    {
        dict.Add(item.Name, 1);
    }

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
}

var json = GenerateProject(new List<MyClass>{
   new MyClass{ Name = "one" },
   new MyClass{ Name = "two" },
   new MyClass{ Name = "three" },
});
// gives {"_id":0,"one":1,"two":1,"three":1}
```